# Inserting page breaks/centering before PDF export

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy all of the charts in my workbook to a temporary sheet, and then export that sheet to a .pdf. I can't seem to figure out how to properly insert a break after each chart, so that each chart has it's own page in the .pdf. As a second goal, I'm also trying to center align each chart in the middle of that page. Here's my code so far:

```
saveLocation = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
fileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")
If saveLocation <> "False" Then
    tp = 25
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.name <> "Start Here" Then
            With wsTemp
                For Each chrt In ws.Shapes
                    'this part works ok, but not sure how to insert the break or center
                    chrt.Copy
                    wsTemp.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
                    Selection.Top = tp
                    Selection.Left = 5
                    tp = tp + Selection.Height + 100
                Next chrt
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With wsTemp.PageSetup
        'cut out PageSetup details for brevity
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True

    wsTemp.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=saveLocation, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
           IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to insert any page breaks directly. Just use the natural ones that Excel displays when print preview is activated and position your charts accordingly in a vertical stack. If you would like to center them in both dimensions on a certain page, get the .`Width` and `.Height` and use that calculate the necessary offset for `.Left` and `.Top` from the upper left corner cell of each chart's page. The easiest way to make sure things are correct is to set the row/column dimensions equal to that of your print area (paper size - margins) so that each cell corresponds with a "page". In a general implementation, it'd be something like:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet 'loop worksheet
Dim pdf As Worksheet 'whatever sheet is the temporary
Dim shp As Shape 'shape holder
Dim i As Long 'loop counter
Dim xDlt As Single, yDlt As Single 'storage variables for the centering

i = 1 'set counter to starting value
Set pdf = printerSheet 'assign the temporary sheet; you can skip this if you just want to use the temporary sheet .CodeName

For Each ws In Worksheets 'loop through sheets as you have

    If (Not ws Is pdf) Then 'make sure you aren't copying the shapes on the temporary sheet; couldnt tell if it was excluded in yours

        For Each shp In ws.Shapes 'loop through shapes as you have; remember that this is based on the only shapes on the sheet being the charts you want to copy

            shp.Copy 'copy the shape
            pdf.Paste 'paste on the pdf sheet
            Application.CutCopyMode = False 'good practice to reset this

            Set shp = pdf.Shapes(shp.Name) 'shape retains the same name when copying so you can obtain copied object reference this way; you no longer need the original object so you can use the same holder variable
            shp.Name = "pdf" & i 'rename the shape to something you are sure is unique; this will cover the case where two charts from different sheets have the same name

            xDlt = pdf.Cells(i, 1).Width - shp.Width 'get the dimensional differences
            yDlt = pdf.Cells(i, 1).Height - shp.Height

            shp.Left = pdf.Cells(i, 1).Left + (xDlt / 2) 'assign the positions accordingly
            shp.Top = pdf.Cells(i, 1).Top + (yDlt / 2)

            i = i + 1 'iterate

        Next

    End If

Next
```

This is not tested and probably isn't 100% optimal but it should be a good starting point.

Comment: @Sudio glad to hear it :)